# Java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: sql-server, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a `jrxml` file. When I run that file in `IReport Designer 4.8.0`, Produces report without fail.
But when I deploy the same file in `JasperServer 5.0.0`, it throws exception.

```
The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.
Error Message

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
Error Trace

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp at     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setTimestamp(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:605) at
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setStatementParameter(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:569) at
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setStatementParameter(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:399) at
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter$1.visit(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:332) at     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter$QueryParameter.accept(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:157) at     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter.visitQueryParameters(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:646) at     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:317) at     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:196) at     com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:168) at     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1086) at
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:667) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1258) at     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877) at
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120) at     com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:859) at     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:165) at     com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$AsynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:821) at     com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1622) at     com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1005) at      com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:881) at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) at     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

The `parameter`, i am passing and `querystring` in `jrxml` file are

```
<parameter name="EndDate" isForPrompting="true" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
    <defaultValueExpression ><![CDATA[new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString><![CDATA[declare @startdate as datetime;
declare @enddate as datetime;
declare @sitegroup as nvarchar(50);
set @startdate = $P{EndDate}-1;
set @enddate = $P{EndDate};
set @sitegroup = 'BBXNCR';
set NOCOUNT ON; -- Added by JC230090: Fixes bug when running query with Jasper

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo]. [#temp_invlines]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[#temp_invlines]
create table #temp_invlines (site_iid uniqueidentifier, invoice_line_type_iid int,   sub_total float, tax_total float,line_total float, product_type_iid int);
insert into #temp_invlines (site_iid,invoice_line_type_iid, sub_total, tax_total,   line_total, product_type_iid)
select h.site_iid, invoice_line_type_iid, l.sub_total, l.tax_total, l.line_total, l.product_type_iid
from invoice_lines l
    inner join invoices h on l.invoice_iid = h.invoice_iid
where h.invoice_dt >= @startdate and h.invoice_dt < @enddate

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[#temp_payment_invoices]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[#temp_payment_invoices]
create table #temp_payment_invoices (site_iid uniqueidentifier, inv_amount float);
insert into #temp_payment_invoices (site_iid, inv_amount)
select i.site_iid, i.total
from invoice_payments p
    inner join Invoice_Payment_Invoice_Xref pXref on p.invoice_payment_iid = pXref.invoice_payment_iid
    inner join invoices i on pXref.invoice_iid = i.invoice_iid
where p.payment_dt >= @startdate and p.payment_dt < @enddate

 IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[#temp_promocodes]') AND type in (N'U'))
 DROP TABLE [dbo].[#temp_promocodes]
 create table #temp_promocodes (site_iid uniqueidentifier, invoice_promo_line_type_iid int, promo_amount float);
 insert into #temp_promocodes (site_iid, invoice_promo_line_type_iid, promo_amount)
select h.site_iid, pl.invoice_promo_line_type_iid, pl.amount
from invoice_promo_lines pl
inner join invoices h on pl.invoice_iid = h.invoice_iid
where h.invoice_dt >= @startdate and h.invoice_dt < @enddate



select 
rtrim(s.site_id) as [Site ID]
, rtrim(ss.Description) as [Status]
, @startdate as [Date]
, datename(dw,@startdate) as [DoW]
, rtrim(s.name) as [Store Code]
, rtrim(isnull(sg.Description,'')) as [Site Group]
, rtrim(s.address1) + ', ' + rtrim(s.city) + ', ' + rtrim(s.state) + ' ' + rtrim(s.Zip)    as [Address]
, rtrim(pg.description) as [RentPriceGroup]

, (select count(*) from invoices h where h.invoice_dt >= @startdate and h.invoice_dt < @enddate and h.site_iid = s.site_iid) as [Trans]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 1) as [Rent Rev]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 2) as [Ext Day Rev]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 0 and l.product_type_iid = 2) as [Used Sell Rev]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 0 and l.product_type_iid <> 2) as [New Sell Rev]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid) as [Rev Total]
, (select isnull(sum(tax_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid) as [Tax Total]
, (select isnull(sum(line_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid) as [Grand Total]
, (select isnull(sum(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid)    /
(select case when count(*) = 0 then 1 else count(*) end from invoices h where h.invoice_dt >= @startdate and h.invoice_dt < @enddate and h.site_iid = s.site_iid)
as [Rev/Trans]
, (select isnull(count(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 1) as [Rent Cnt]
, (select isnull(count(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 2) as [Ext Day Cnt]
, (select isnull(count(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 0 and l.product_type_iid = 2) as [Used Sell Cnt]
, (select isnull(count(sub_total),0) from #temp_invlines l where l.site_iid = s.site_iid and l.invoice_line_type_iid = 0 and l.product_type_iid <> 2) as [New Sell Cnt]
, (select isnull(count(promo_amount),0) from #temp_promocodes p where p.site_iid = s.site_iid and p.invoice_promo_line_type_iid = 0) as [CustSrv Promo Cnt]
, (select isnull(sum(promo_amount),0) from #temp_promocodes p where p.site_iid = s.site_iid and p.invoice_promo_line_type_iid = 0) as [CustSrv Promo Amt]
, (select isnull(count(promo_amount),0) from #temp_promocodes p where p.site_iid = s.site_iid and p.invoice_promo_line_type_iid = 1) as [Marketing Promo Cnt]
, (select isnull(sum(promo_amount),0) from #temp_promocodes p where p.site_iid = s.site_iid and p.invoice_promo_line_type_iid = 1) as [Marketing Promo Amt]

, (SELECT  
    isnull(count(*),0)
FROM Invoice_Lines ilrtn 
    INNER JOIN Invoices ihrtn on ilrtn.invoice_iid = ihrtn.invoice_iid 
    inner join customer_ids c on ihrtn.customer_id_iid = c.customer_id_iid
    INNER JOIN Invoices ihrent on ihrtn.customer_id_iid = ihrent.customer_id_iid  
    INNER JOIN Invoice_lines ilrent on ihrent.invoice_iid = ilrent.invoice_iid 
WHERE ihrtn.invoice_dt >= @startdate
    and ihrtn.invoice_dt < @enddate
    and ilrtn.invoice_line_type_iid in (0,2)
    AND ihrent.invoice_dt <= ihrtn.invoice_dt 
    AND ilrent.invoice_line_type_iid in (1) 
    AND ilrent.piece_id = ilrtn.piece_id 
    and ihrtn.site_iid = s.site_iid 
) as [Invoices]

, (SELECT  
    isnull(sum(ilrent.line_total + ilrtn.line_total),0)
FROM Invoice_Lines ilrtn 
    INNER JOIN Invoices ihrtn on ilrtn.invoice_iid = ihrtn.invoice_iid 
    inner join customer_ids c on ihrtn.customer_id_iid = c.customer_id_iid
    INNER JOIN Invoices ihrent on ihrtn.customer_id_iid = ihrent.customer_id_iid  
    INNER JOIN Invoice_lines ilrent on ihrent.invoice_iid = ilrent.invoice_iid 
WHERE ihrtn.invoice_dt >= @startdate
    and ihrtn.invoice_dt < @enddate
    and ilrtn.invoice_line_type_iid in (0,2)
    AND ihrent.invoice_dt <= ihrtn.invoice_dt 
    AND ilrent.invoice_line_type_iid in (1) 
    AND ilrent.piece_id = ilrtn.piece_id 
    and ihrtn.site_iid = s.site_iid 
) as [Collectable]


, ( select isnull(sum(p.amount),0)
from invoice_payments p
where p.payment_dt >= @startdate and p.payment_dt < @enddate
and p.invoice_payment_iid in (
    select distinct p.invoice_payment_iid
    from invoice_payments p
    inner join Invoice_Payment_Invoice_Xref pXref on p.invoice_payment_iid = pXref.invoice_payment_iid
    inner join invoices i on pXref.invoice_iid = i.invoice_iid
    where p.payment_dt >= @startdate and p.payment_dt < @enddate
    and i.site_iid = s.site_iid
    group by p.invoice_payment_iid, pXref.invoice_iid)
) as [Payments Collected]
from sites s
inner join Site_Statuses_Enum ss on s.site_status_iid = ss.site_status_iid
inner join Site_Rent_Price_Groups as pg on s.site_rent_price_group_iid =     pg.site_rent_price_group_iid
left outer join Site_SiteGroup_XRef sgx on s.site_iid = sgx.site_iid
left outer join Site_Groups sg on sgx.site_group_iid = sg.site_group_iid
where sg.Description in (@sitegroup) or sg.Description is null
order by s.site_id

drop table #temp_promocodes
drop table #temp_payment_invoices
drop table #temp_invlines;]]></queryString>
```

Please Help me...

Comment: can you show sample code?

Comment: @JW. I added `jrxml` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the parameter default value expression to the following

`new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())`